# Databricks 9.1 Cluster cannot access /Workspace

Tags: databricks

When I try to access /Workspace from the code, I am getting error message like below.

ls: cannot open directory '/Workspace': Resource temporarily unavailable

I am using multi node cluster with 9.1.
When I try it from 13.3 it works fine, but we can not move to upper level yet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

9.1 has support for arbitrary files only in Repos, not in the Workspace that was added in 11.3 as mentioned by Eric. But if you have Databricks Repo, then you can access `/Workspace/Repos/...`, although just read-only.

Please note that init scripts from workspace files work on all supported versions.

P.S. It's recommended to upgrade to at least 11.3, not necessary to go to 13.3...

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I have Repos set up, but since I am not able to access to the Workspace, I am not available for Repos as well. Do I need to configure something?

Comment: Check workspace settings - there is a setting for repos specifying the min version…

Answer (score 0):

Quoting from: https://docs.databricks.com/en/files/workspace.html

> Workspace files are enabled everywhere by default in Databricks Runtime version 11.2, but can be disabled by admins using the REST API.